# Escape $ in Eclipse for rpath

Tags: eclipse

So, these are my linker options:

```
-Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN
```

No matter what amount of escapes I do, I can't get it from transforming into:

```
-Wl,-rpath,\RIGIN
```

etc, without the \ if I don't try to escape. I figure this comes from the workspace location escape, but what do?

Comment: Is $ORIGIN an environment variable? You can try `-Wl,-rpath,${env_var:ORIGIN}`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found in some obscure comment on another question(don't have the link), that `$$` -> `$` to escape.